# Django: string in list (templates)

Tags: django, django-templates

How can I see if a variable is in a list of strings? I get an error with that code:

```
{% with xxx=request.resolver_match.url_name %}
  {% if xxx in ["home_en", "page_en"] %}
  ...
  {% else %}
  ...
  {% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: The error says: Could not parse the remainder: '["home_en",' from '["home_en",'

Answer (score 0):

You can't define list dynamically in your django templates.
You should pass this list as a variable it to your templates through your view's context or using context processor.

As a dirty sollution you are able to perform something like this
{% if xxx in 'home_enpage_en' %}

but be aware that values like 'home', 'enpage', '_en' will actually pass this check as well as 'home_en' and 'page_en'.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I guess I prefer

```
{% if xxx == "home_en" or xxx == "page_en" %}
```

which works fine but doesn't look as nice as with the list.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
{% with request.resolver_match.url_name as xxx %}
  {% with "home_en page_en" as mylist %}
  {% if xxx in mylist.split %}
  ...
  {% else %}
  ...
  {% endif %}
  {% endwith %}
{% endwith %}
```